# render Django HTML tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, django-contrib

I have installed in my project django-contib-comments and I have an HTML that displays the list of comments and also displays the form to enter a new one.

I now want to use Ajax to submit the form without a page refresh and on success to add the submitted comment to the list.

I have done most of the work, but I'm sure there must be an easier way to achieve this.

my question is if there is a way for me to render a Django HTML tag within a javascript something like this:

```
 document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = {% render_comment_list for obj %}
```

so far this is the code I have done:

1) I don't want to change anything in the django-contrib-comments project (i am avoiding to override methods.

2) I used the standard tags in django-contrib-comments to render a list of comments.

```
   {% render_comment_list for obj %}
```

3) Created a JavaScript that handles the submit of the form and then creates a new entry in the list.

```
function submit_comments(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        type: $('#comment_form').attr('method'),
        url: $('#comment_form').attr('action'),
        data: $('#comment_form').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (html, textStatus) {
            var comment_count_btn = document.getElementById('comment-text-vertical-btn');
            if (comment_count_btn != null) {
                if (!isNaN(parseInt(comment_count_btn.innerHTML))) {
                    comment_count_btn.innerHTML = parseInt(comment_count_btn.innerHTML) + 1 + " Comments";
                }
            }
            var comment_count_head = document.getElementById('kapua-comments-header');
            if (comment_count_head != null) {
                if (!isNaN(parseInt(comment_count_head.innerHTML))) {
                    comment_count_head.innerHTML = parseInt(comment_count_head.innerHTML) + 1 + " Comments:";
                }
            }

            if (document.getElementById("comments") != null){
                submitted_timestamp = getQueryParameter("timestamp", this.data);
                submitted_date = new Date();
                if (submitted_timestamp == null) {
                    submitted_date = new Date(submitted_timestamp);
                }

                submitted_comment = getQueryParameter("comment", this.data);
                if (submitted_comment == null) {
                    submitted_comment = "No value entered"
                }

                html_comment = "<div class=\"right-aligned\"><div class=\"comment-date\">" + submitted_date + " - " + "</div>" + submitted_comment + "</div><br><br>";
                current_html = document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = html_comment + current_html;
            }

            if (document.getElementById("comment_form") != null){
                document.getElementById("comment_form").reset();
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#comment_form').replaceWith('Your comment was unable to be posted at this time.  We apologise for the inconvenience.');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, you can use Django template tags/filters in on-page scripts, if the contents of the script depend on some server-side data. Did you try it?

Comment: Is the `submit_comments()` function embedded inside a Django template, or does it live in its own Javascript file?

Comment: @RobinZigmond: can you please elaborate, what do you mean with on-page scripts?

Comment: @WillKeeling: it lives in its own javascript file

Comment: @SheldonLipshitz I just meant scripts within `<script>` tags in your Django template. (As opposed to scripts loaded from separate `.js` files, which obviously can't use the Django template language.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way in django, You can use `[escape][1]` to render HTML tag. Here is an simple example -

```
from django.utils.html import escape
def example(request):
    return "%s<div><i>%s</i></div>" % (escape(text), escape(other_text)
```

For more explanation you can refer to documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape

Still have any doubts comment it out.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, 

The code that you are suggesting is by using python, i want to call the django html tag as part of my JavaScript.

Comment: You can't use django HTML tags in JavaScript files (.js files), if you want to use django HTML tag in js then you must write your script in HTML file only.
In `.html` you can easily use django Tags anywhere.